# Support for Broadcast

Tags: networking, ip, router

I'm working on a research paper that may rely heavily on broadcasting. I've written a small prototype application to test broadcasting in a university setting, and everything works as expected.

I've been told that broadcasting is typically disabled in most networks. Does anyone have any insight on this? I'm most concerned with small/medium sized public networks, like local Starbucks, airports, etc.

I would be interested in broadcasting only across the same subnet, nothing wider. Is this typically disabled in most networks today?

Comment: basically this will be disabled to prevent DDoS attack like [Smurf Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smurf_attack).

Comment: But that could be prevented by disabling ICMP within the network. Which, as I understand it, is also very likely. (Pick up on the fact that I am not a practicing network admin).

Comment: Correct, typically in data center this will be disabled for host communication, but only enabled for network devices. Unless the application requirement needs a broadcast then this will be an exclusion rule. However for public hotspot, i dont think this is being implemented.

Comment: `I've been told that broadcasting is typically disabled in most networks` - That's a fairly vague and nebulous statement. Without having any details about what this person meant when they told you that, it's impossible to answer. That being said, Ethernet based networks would be rendered useless and inoperable if **ALL** broadcasts were disabled as ARP uses broadcasts (as just one example).